# LyX issue with the viewer

Tags: lyx, pdf

I just installed MiKTeX and LyX on my new Apple laptop (yosemite 10.10).
When I open an old `.lyx` file or create a new one the eyes icon on the top left (`cmd R`) for creating a PDF is inactive, as well as the for other icons on the right. If I click in the documents settings on "use non TeX fonts" then the eyes are active.

One users on this group said he solved this problem by deleting the directory `.../Libaray/Application Support/Lyx.../` and restarting LyX 
Unfortunately, I am not an expert and I can't find this directory.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. There was a conflict with an old version of Lyx on my max. So I deleted all directories Libary/Application Support/Lyx and reinstalled Lyx.
Problem solved. 
best regards
Jean-Christophe